# Android recyclerview scroll to position

Tags: android

```
Public class spinFragment extends AbstractSpinningFragment {

Context context;
private ExpandableAdapter expandableAdapter;

@BindView(R.id.recycler)
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentSpin, container, false);

    this.sectionWebContentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(this.expandableAdapter);

    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(10);

    return fragmentView;
}
```

I want to scroll to position 10 in my recyclerview. But it doesn't do anything.

I also tried: recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(12);
and smooth scrolling.

Anyone knows that the problem is?

Comment: where did you set data on recyclerview?

Comment: also where did you initialize your `expandableAdapter` class?